# No recupera nada de la base de datos si no refresco el contexto de la aplicacion

Tags: mysql

Muy buenas, espero que me podáis ayudar.
Resulta que estoy trabajando en una aplicación web, y tengo el siguiente problema (que luego he averiguado que me pasa con todas las aplicaciones).

Tengo una base de datos de una tienda de informática, y lo primero que hago es recuperar las categorías para que se pueda navegar de un lado a otro de la aplicación buscando componentes.

Pues bien, la primera operación que hago contra la base de datos es la de obtener las categorías, aquí entran en juego una clase dao, y el controlador, bien, despues de obtener estas categorias, si quieres acceder por ejemplo a los procesadores, tengo que ejecutar otro metodo de un dao específico, que este es el dao de productos, bien, pues como he dicho antes, despues de haber recuperado las categorias, ya no me recupera los productos de la categoria que yo quiero.

Es decir, obtengo las categorias con el metodo dao de categorias para obtener estas, y despues todas las operaciones que haga contra la base de datos, no me funciona por que no me obtiene ningun dato de la base de datos, sorry por la redundancia.

Muchas gracias a quien me solucione esto.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack, como sugerencia pon el código con lo que estas trabajando para que asi sea más fácil que esta comunidad te pueda orientar.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida. Volviendo al tema, no hay error de código, el problema es algo mas, porque no me funciona ninguna aplicación como antes, después de ejecutar por primera vez cualquiera de la operaciones contra la base de datos, ya no funciona ninguna mas, porque no me obtienen los datos después de ese primer ataque contra la BBDD.

Comment: Es bastante dificil estimar una solución sin que coloques el código pero puede que en la primera consulta que ejecutas está la instrucción de cierre de la conexión a la base de datos y debido a ello cualquier otra consulta que intentes después no será ejecutada